# Play framework 2.3.7 Utf-8 escape in conf/messages

Tags: scala, utf-8, playframework, internationalization

I'm a beginner in scala and working on the example project in "play 2 for scala".

Now I want to know how to escape special characters in a conf/messages file so that it is properly presented.

My conf/messages.es:

```
new.submit = A{small n with tilde}adir
```

So, how do i write this letter?
I tried without success:

```
\u00f1
\x00f1
&#00f1;
```

and many more...

Then, somewhere in my view, I have the following expression to test it:

```
@Messages("new.submit")
```

Output on the rendered html page is for example: "A\u00f1adir"

What do I do wrong?
Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Why do you want to escape it? Just write your text and save it UTF-8 encoded. This should just work, no?

Comment: Why would you want to escape it? Play supports UTF-8 out of the box. Try this: `new.submit=Añadir`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. You say that I should just copy the ñ into the file. That is the simple solution.But i wanted a solution where i can write the utf-8 code of the symbol instead of the copied symbol. I just wonder if it's possible.